# What does `auto &&i = foo();` mean

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding-reference

Please explain how auto type deduction works when used with move semantic:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    static void type() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

float& bar() {
    static float t = 5.5;
    return t;
}

int foo() {
    return 5;
}

int main() {
    auto &&a1 = foo();  // I expected auto -> int    (wrong)
    auto &&a2 = bar();  // I expected auto -> float& (correct)

    A<decltype(a1)>::type();
    A<decltype(a2)>::type();
}
```

The output is:

```
static void A<T>::type() [with T = int&&]
static void A<T>::type() [with T = float&]
```

Comment: Your output shows `int` and `float`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of a variable with type auto&&?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230480/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-variable-with-type-auto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto&&` (just like `T&&` in parameter of a function template where `T` is a template parameter of that function template) follows slightly different rules than other deductions - it's unofficially called a "universal reference."

The idea is that if the initialiser is an lvalue of type `X`, the `auto` is deduced to `X&`. If it's an rvalue of type `X`, the `auto` is deduced to `X`. In both cases, `&&` is then applied normally. From reference collapsing rules, `X& &&` becomes `X&`, while `X &&` remains `X&&`.

This means that in your `a1` case, `auto` is indeed deduced to `int`, but `a1` is then naturally declared with type `int&&`, and that's what `decltype(a1)` gives you.

At the same time, the `auto` in `a2` is `float&`, and so is the type of `a2`, which the `decltype(a2)` again confirms.

In other words, your expectation that `auto -> int` in the first case is correct, but the type of `a1` is `auto &&a1`, not just `auto a1`.

Comment: Are there anything I should be aware of with variables deduced to "type &&", or will they always behave as "type"? (in this example will a "int&&" always behave the same as a regular int)

Comment: @Allan If it's been initialised from a prvalue, I can't think of anything (except for `decltype`) where you could tell a difference. However, if the thing it refers to can change, you'll observe the change through the `int&&` reference, but you wouldn't through an `int` copy.

Answer (score 2):

`auto &&a1 = foo();`

Return type of `foo()` is int. Since you declared a1 as `auto&&`, it expands to `int&&`, and that is what you get for type of a1.

`auto &&a2 = bar();`

Return type of `bar()` is float&. Since you declared a2 as `auto&&`, it expands to `float& &&` and that converts to `float&` following the rules.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371167/476681) explains the rules how the universal reference expands :

```
&& -> &&
&& & -> &
& && -> &
&& && -> &&
```