# How does std::forward receive the correct argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Consider:

```cpp
void g(int&);
void g(int&&);

template<class T>
void f(T&& x)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(x));
}

int main()
{
    f(10);
}
```

Since the id-expression `x` is an lvalue, and `std::forward` has overloads  for lvalues and rvalues, why doesn't the call bind to the overload of `std::forward` that takes an lvalue?

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr T&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;
```

Comment: For a "long" answer, see Thomas Becker's excellent article on rvalue references: http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html. Your question is discussed in section 7 and 8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It *does* bind to the overload of `std::forward` taking an lvalue:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;
```

It binds with `T == int`.  This function is specified to return:

```
static_cast<T&&>(t)
```

Because the `T` in `f` deduced to `int`.  So this overload casts the lvalue `int` to xvalue with:

```
static_cast<int&&>(t)
```

Thus calling the `g(int&&)` overload.

In summary, the lvalue overload of `std::forward` may cast its argument to either lvalue or rvalue, depending upon the type of `T` that it is called with.

The rvalue overload of `std::forward` can only cast to rvalue.  If you try to call that overload and cast to lvalue, the program is ill-formed (a compile-time error is required).

So overload 1:

```
template <class T>
constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;
```

catches lvalues.

Overload 2:

```
template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept;
```

catches rvalues (which is xvalues and prvalues).

Overload 1 can cast its lvalue argument to lvalue or xvalue (the latter which will be interpreted as an rvalue for overload resolution purposes).

Overload 2 can can cast its rvalue argument only to an xvalue (which will be interpreted as an rvalue for overload resolution purposes).

Overload 2 is for the case labeled "B. Should forward an rvalue as an rvalue" in [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html).  In a nutshell this case enables:

```
std::forward<T>(u.get());
```

where you are unsure if `u.get()` returns an lvalue or rvalue, but either way if `T` is not an lvalue reference type, you want to move the returned value.  But you don't use `std::move` because if `T` *is* an lvalue reference type, you *don't* want to move from the return.

I know this sounds a bit contrived.  However [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) went to significant trouble to set up *motivating* use cases for how `std::forward` should behave with all combinations of the explicitly supplied template parameter, and the implicitly supplied expression category of the ordinary parameter.

It isn't an easy read, but the rationale for each combination of template and ordinary parameters to `std::forward` is in [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html).  At the time this was controversial on the committee, and not an easy sell.

The final form of `std::forward` is not exactly what [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html) proposed.  However it *does* pass all six tests presented in [N2951](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2951.html).

Answer (score 9):

> why doesn't the call bind to the overload of `std::forward` that takes an lvalue?

It does exactly that, but `std::forward` [does not deduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7779900/241631) its template argument, you tell it what type it is, and that's where the magic occurs. You're passing a prvalue to `f()` so `f()` deduces `[T = int]`. It then calls the lvalue overload of `forward`, and due to [reference collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371167/241631) both the return type and `static_cast<T&&>` that happens within `forward` will be of type `int&&`, thus calling the `void g(int&&)` overload.

If you were to pass an lvalue to `f()`

```
int x = 0;
f(x);
```

`f()` deduces `[T = int&]`, again the same lvalue overload of `forward` gets called, but this time the return type and `static_cast<T&&>` are both `int&`, again because of the reference collapsing rules. This will then call the `void g(int&)` overload instead.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae929e07de297ba)

---

Howard already has a good answer for your question about why the rvalue overload of `forward` is required, but I'll add a contrived example that shows the two versions in action.

The basic idea behind the two overloads is that the rvalue overload will be invoked in cases where the result of the expression you pass to `forward` yields an rvalue (prvalue or xvalue).

Say you have a type `foo` that has a ref-qualified pair of `get()` member function overloads. The one with the `&&` qualifier returns an `int` while the other returns `int&`.

```
struct foo
{
    int i = 42;
    int  get() && { return i; }
    int& get() &  { return i; }
};
```

And say `f()` invokes the `get()` member function on whatever was passed to it, and forwards that on to `g()`

```
template<class T>
auto f(T&& t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    g(forward<decltype(forward<T>(t).get())>(forward<T>(t).get()));
}

foo foo1;
f(foo1);   // calls lvalue overload of forward for both calls to forward

f(std::move(foo1)); // calls lvalue overload of forward for forward<T>(t)
                    // but calls rvalue overload for outer call to forward
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/044d82bb4c7b87e8)

Comment: What is the rvalue overload for?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to call `forward<T>(std::move(t))` without the second overload, because rvalue references are not auto-convertible to lvalue references. In the inner _forward_ (i.e. `forward<T>(t)`) the argument `t` is lvalue and the first overload is chosen. In the outer _forward_ (i.e. `forward<decltype(...)>(...)`) the argument (the value returned by the inner _forward_) is rvalue reference and the second overload is chosen. Ok, I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

### How does std::forward receive the correct argument?

For perfect forwarding,as your code:

```
template<class T>
void f(T&& x)
{
    g(std::forward<T>(x));
}
```

Note this:std::forward requires both a function argument and a template type argument.
 **The template parameter T will encode whether the argument passed to param was an lvalue or an rvalue** and then forward use it.
In this case,not matter `x` refer what ,`x` itself is an lvalue,choice overload 1 ,and **x is forwarding(universal) reference parameters.Rules as follow:**

1. if `f` the argument's expr is lvalue ，Both `x` and `T` will lvalue reference
   type
2. if `f` the argument's expr is rvalue ，`T` will be non-reference type.

**For example use gcc source code :**

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr _Tp&&
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
    { return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t); } //overload 1


  template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr _Tp&&
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
    {
      static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value, "template argument"
            " substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type");
      return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
    }// overload 2
```

- if pass function f lvalue of type is `string` or `string&`,for
  forward function `_Tp` will be `string&`,`__t` will be `string & &`
  is equal to `string&`,`_Tp&&` will be `string& &&` is equal to
  `string&`.（reference collapsing）
- if pass function f rvalue of type is `string` or `string&&`,for
  forward function `_Tp` will be `string`,`__t` will be
  `string&`,`_Tp&&` will be `string&&`.

### What the function do?

- if rvalue to rvalue(Overload 2) or lvalue to lvalue(Overload 1) ,nothing to do,just return.
- If you're not careful or something else, lead rvalue to lvalue, gives you a compilation error by `static_assert`.(Overload 2)
- If you do lvalue to rvalue(Overload 1),it is same with std::move,but not convenience.

So just as Scott Meyers say:

> Given that both std::move and std::forward boil down to casts, the
>   only difference being that std::move always casts, while
>   std::forward only sometimes does, you might ask whether we can
>   dispense with std::move and just use std::forward everywhere. **From a
>   purely technical perspective, the answer is yes: std::forward can do
>   it all.** std::move isn’t necessary. Of course, neither function is
>   really necessary, because we could write casts everywhere, but I
>   hope we agree that that would be, well, yucky.

### What is the rvalue overload for?

I'm not sure, it should be used where you really need it.Such as Howard Hinnant says:

> Overload 2 is for the case labeled "B. Should forward an rvalue as an
>   rvalue" in N2951. In a nutshell this case enables:
>
> `std::forward<T>(u.get());`
>
> where you are unsure if u.get() returns an lvalue or rvalue, but
>   either way if T is not an lvalue reference type, you want to move the
>   returned value. But you don't use std::move because if T is an lvalue
>   reference type, you don't want to move from the return.

**In a word,it allow us use T's type to decide whether move or not.**