# How do two overloaded std::forward work?

Tags: c++, c++11, forward-declaration

I have found in std library the following implementation of std::forward:

```
// TEMPLATE FUNCTION forward
template<class _Ty> inline
constexpr _Ty&& forward(
    typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
{   // forward an lvalue as either an lvalue or an rvalue
return (static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Arg));
}

template<class _Ty> inline
constexpr _Ty&& forward(
    typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
{   // forward an rvalue as an rvalue
static_assert(!is_lvalue_reference<_Ty>::value, "bad forward call");
return (static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Arg));
}
```

First function works obviously, but for second I cannot find usefull example.
If I try to do something like this:

```
template<class _Ty> inline
constexpr _Ty&& my_forward(
   typename std::remove_reference<_Ty>::type&& _Arg) _NOEXCEPT
{   // forward an rvalue as an rvalue
   static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Ty>::value, "bad forward call");
   return (static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Arg));
}

template<typename T>
T getRValue()
{
    return std::remove_reference<T>::type{};
}

template<typename T>
void setValue(T && i)
{
   my_forward<T>(getRValue<T>());
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    setValue(i);
}
```

to check when second function is called, I have got the error:

```
Error   C2664   '_Ty my_forward<T>(int &&) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'
```

Does anybody know in which case second overloaded function (in my terms my_forward) is called ?
Or may be some good example for it ?
By the way my compiler is MSVC 2015

Thanks, all for help !!

Comment: The comment says "forward an rvalue as an rvalue" but you forward an <strike>rvalue</strike> lvalue as an lvalue (and have a case of undefined behavior aswell). That's not what the function is written for.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: Why ? getRValue() provide prvalue and it can be put as parameter to my_forward. Could you give a usefull example of using my_forward for rvalue as in my example ?

Comment: @DenisKotov: "*getRValue() provide prvalue*" Does it? It returns a `T`, but `T` can be a reference. And thus, it could be an lvalue.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: Sorry for incorrect. It is _xvalue_, but not _lvalue_, because return value of function can be reused, but it does not have a name yet

Comment: This is also very relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29135698/241631

Comment: @Praetorian: I have been interested in which cases called second overloaded and have figured out it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found cases in which this function is called:

```
my_forward<int&>(8); // This calls forward(typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&& _Arg)
But it won't compile 'cause we try convert rvalue to lvalue

my_forward<int&&>(8); // This calls forward(typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&& _Arg)
But it compiles successfully
```

If it may be useful for somebody, the purpose of **std::forward** is to forward operation to another class or function.

Consider the following example:

```
template<typename T>
void precompute(T & t)
{
   std::cout << "lvalue reference";
}

template<typename T, 
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value, bool> = true>
void precompute(T && t)
{
   std::cout << "rvalue reference";
}

template<typename T>
void calculate(T && t)
{
   precompute(t); // Every time called precompute(T & t)
}
```

or like this:

```
template<typename T>
void precompute(T & t)
{
   std::cout << "lvalue reference";
}

template<typename T, 
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value, bool> = true>
void precompute(T && t)
{
   std::cout << "rvalue reference";
}

template<typename T>
void calculate(T && t)
{
   precompute(std::move(t)); // Every time called precompute(T && t)
}
```

As you can see we have a problem !! Neither of two examples satisfied us.

In first example every time will be called **lvalue** function and nothing can be done to call first with **rvalue**.

In second example every time will be called **rvalue** function and nothing can be done to call first with **lvalue**.

The solution is to forward making decision to the called function:

```
template<typename T>
void precompute(T & t)
{
   std::cout << "lvalue reference";
}

template<typename T, 
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value, bool> = true>
void precompute(T && t)
{
   std::cout << "rvalue reference";
}

template<typename T>
void calculate(T && t)
{
   precompute(std::forward<T>(t)); // Will be called either precompute(T & t) or precompute(T && t) depends on type of t
}
```

In this case we have to be sure that will be called appropriate version.
That is why we forward (means: "*Please, check type of t and if it is **rvalue** -> call **rvalue** version of function, and if it is **lvalue** -> call **lvalue** version of function*") this operation to called function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int bad_forward_call() {
  return std::forward<int&>(7);
}
```

this will invoke that version.

Note I'm forwarding an rvalue as an lvalue.  Not allowed.

Your `getRValue` fails to get an rvalue if `T` is a reference type.

Comment: No, this version is not call that version. It even not compiles due to static assert

Comment: @DenisKotov There is a `static_assert` in that version... which I believe I'm hitting.