# c++11 - std::forward with rvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I do understand the nature of `std::forward` when it comes to, well, forwarding a lvalue argument as a lvalue or rvalue, depending on the template parameter's "value-ness".

But I just noticed that [this page of cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) contains the other way of using it, namely with rvalues. Declaration is as follows:

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t ) noexcept;
//note double ampersand
```

And the brief description is like this:

> 2. Forwards rvalues as rvalues and prohibits forwarding of rvalues as
>    lvalues

What problem does it solve? The only reason I was able to come up with is that it may be used as an additional check for correctness of wrapper function call, that is, if I plan to supply the internal function with an rvalue, then the wrapper should be called solely with an rvalue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Howard answers this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29135698/817643), along with receipts.

Comment: Have a look at the example on cppreference. The use case is to write correct, optimized template code.

Comment: The first overload cannot turn a rvalue into an rvalue reference and this is expected of `std::forward`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I'm looking at the cppreference example, and it boils down to `std::forward<decltype(foo())>(foo())` which looks like a useless identity transformation. Note that OP asks only about the overload with the `&&` argument.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you for introducing the `identity transformation` notion. My question was mostly about it - why paying any additional attention to prvalue, if it is already clear that it is a prvalue?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica hey! I've read the referred answer and the B use case in the mentioned article, and this is not yet clear for me why exactly it is needed. The example that they are providing seems to be rather contrived to me. `C(U&& u) : t_(std::forward<T>(std::move(u).get())) {}` - in this example from the article, why would I even bother putting an output of std::move into std::forward? It is already a prvalue, why forwarding?

Comment: @fabian but I am just failing to see why would I want that (probably because I'm not an experienced cpp dev, I do recognize that). It is done for the sake of covering all the use cases possible *just in case*?

Comment: @AntonTretyakov - It's not the output of `move`, it's the output of `get()` you are attempting to forward. Imagine `T` is some `R&`, and that `U::get() &&` returns a `R&&`.  If the second overload did not stop here (i.e. it only casted blindly), you'd be holding on to a dangling reference.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica so, I see `move` is here to get a correct overload of `U::get()`, namely the `&&` one. But that's not exactly clear for me how dangling reference comes into play, could you elaborate on it a little bit more?
In addition, in the mentioned article `get()` just return by value - why forwarding? To avoid additional copy?

Comment: Returning `R` or `R&&` has the same problem here, so that's not a major difference. Here's the problem illustrated https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tb4H8Je13EjLcwts.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica the link's giving an error, unfortunately.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9EorPWohT

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, so it is blocking rvalue from converting to lvalue, this is the mechanism. But why do I need it? And how it is related to dangling references?

I mean, yeah, if I play a bit with your example and make the first template parameter `const` then it will work without `forward` and then I will have a dangling reference in `c` after the temporary `A` is destructed - and in such a case `forward` acts like a safety measure. Is it the case?

Comment: If it wasn't blocked, that reference in C would have been bound to the member of the temporary object I initialized with `{}`. That *is* dangling.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yes, so that is the safety measure I am talking about. But why would I want to use `get()` at first place, especially combined with `move`? I mean, it seems for me that this second `forward` overload is solving the problem that is purely made-up at first place - my understanding is that you shouldn't bind members of one object to members of another (until they are explicitly shared) at all to start with.

Comment: It's not purely made up. That example accepted an rvalue in the constructor (it wasn't a forwarding reference). Objects may overload members to behave differently for rvalues (usually more efficiently). It's only natural to move there to allow such an overload to be called if it exists. The second forward is to adjust the return value to the expected type of the member. Nothing is done "just because". It's a rare usage pattern, but not a contrived one. Either way, comments are not for extended discussions, so I'm signing off here.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica well, your last comment made something click in my head! Thanks for your time mate, this case now seems to be clear!