# Filtering a tuple in boost hana

Tags: c++, boost-hana

```
template<class... Ts, class T>
constexpr auto contains(T&&){
  auto types = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(hana::tuple_t<Ts...>);
  return hana::bool_c<hana::find(types, hana::type_c<T>) != hana::nothing>;
}

auto ht = hana::make_tuple(1,2,3,'c');

auto ht1 = hana::filter(ht, [](auto t){
  return contains<int,float,double>(t);
});
//prints 0
std::cout << hana::size(ht1) << std::endl;
```

I am not sure if I am using boost hana correctly but `contains` seems to work.

```
std::cout << contains<int,float,double>(5) << std::endl;   // 1
std::cout << contains<int,float,double>('c') << std::endl; // 0
std::cout << contains<int,float,double>(5.0f) << std::endl; // 1
```

Why is the size of `ht1` 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here actually has nothing to do with Hana, it has to do with the way universal references are deduced. Just to clear up things, `hana::type_c<T> == hana::type_c<U>` is precisely equivalent to `std::is_same<T, U>{}`. There is no reference or cv-qualifier removing when comparing `hana::type`s. You can look at various articles (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371167/627587) or [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c/)) for these rules.

Now, let me go through your code and modify some things, with comments. First,

```
  auto types = hana::to<hana::tuple_tag>(hana::tuple_t<Ts...>);
```

is redundant, because you're already creating a `hana::tuple` with `hana::tuple_t`. Hence, `hana::tuple_t<T...>` only is sufficient. Secondly, there's this line:

```
  return hana::bool_c<hana::find(types, hana::type_c<T>) != hana::nothing>;
```

Instead of checking `hana::find(...) != hana::nothing`, I would instead use `hana::contains`, which expresses your intent better and might be more optimized too. In general, and especially with a metaprogramming library with Hana, don't try to reason as to what will be faster. Just state your intent as clearly as possible and hope for me to do my job properly on the implementation side :-). Hence, you'll end up with

```
return hana::bool_c<hana::contains(types, hana::type_c<T>)>;
```

Now, that `hana::bool_c<...>` really is redundant, because `hana::contains` already returns a boolean `integral_constant`. Hence, the above is equivalent to the simpler

```
return hana::contains(types, hana::type_c<T>);
```

Finally, putting all the bits together and simplifying, you get

```
template<class... Ts, class T>
constexpr auto contains(T&&){
  return hana::contains(hana::tuple_t<Ts...>, hana::type_c<T>);
}
```

I'm personally not a fan of taking the `T&&` as an argument, when all you want is actually the type of that object. Indeed, that forces you to actually provide an **object** to `contains` function, which might be unwieldy in some circumstances (what if you don't have an object around?). Furthermore, it can be confusing to be comparing values with types:

```
contains<int, char, double>(3.5) // wtf, 3.5 is not in [int, char, double]!
```

Instead, I would write the following if it was my own code:

```
template<class... Ts, class T>
constexpr auto contains(T type){
  return hana::contains(hana::tuple_t<Ts...>, type);
}

// and then use it like
contains<int, char, double>(hana::type_c<double>)
```

But that is part of the interface of your function, and I guess you are a better judge than I to know what your needs are in terms of interface.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `T&&`, I think it deduces the type to be of type `T&` which means that `hana::type_c<T> != hana::type_c<T&>` The fix is to leave the `&&` because they are unnecessary.

```
template<class... Ts, class T>
constexpr auto contains(T){
  auto types = hana::tuple_t<Ts...>;
  return hana::find(types, hana::type_c<T>) != hana::nothing;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to your answer, your `ht1` was calling `contains` with `t` an lvalue. The following demonstrates `T&&` in the case of passing an rvalue and an lvalue:

```
#include<boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<class T>
void test1(T&&) {
  static_assert(hana::type_c<T> == hana::type_c<int>, "");
}

int main() {
  static_assert(hana::type_c<int> != hana::type_c<int&&>, "");
  test1(5);
  int x = 5;
  test1(x); //fails
}
```

clang output:

```
main.cpp:7:3: error: static_assert failed ""
  static_assert(hana::type_c<T> == hana::type_c<int>, "");
  ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'test1<int &>' requested here
  test1(x); //fails
  ^
1 error generated.
```